# Verifying a PDF derived from a CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification

If I have a CDF of a continuous random variable $x>0$, and derived its PDF by differentiating the CDF, how to verify that this PDF is correct is there a relation or a certain plot between the PDF and CDF that prove that the pdf is correct for this CDF ?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the expression "continuous random variable $X$" does not make sense at all(remember that a random variable is a function from $\Omega$ $\rightarrow$ R and $\Omega$ is usually too abstract and the notion of continuity can't be used about functions with the domain in $\Omega$). what you mean is that you have a function $F$ that describes the distribution of $X$ and $F$ is continuous.
Now turning to your question, the easiest way is probably to take the integral from $-\infty$ to $x$ of  $tf(t)$  and see it equals $F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

PDF aren't unique, so you're right asking yourself if there's a way to connect CDF and PDF. There are two results which I'm familiar to

> $F$ CDF for a probability $P$ has density if
>
> 1. $F$ is piecewise continuous over $\Bbb R$
> 2. $F$ is piecewise $C^1$
>
> In this case $f(x) = \frac{dF(x)}{dx}$

The second one

> Let $f:\Bbb R \to [0,+\infty)$ Borelian function, and a probability $P$ over $\Bbb R$. Let $F(x)$ be is CDF. $f$ is a PDF for $P\iff F(x) \int_{-\infty}^xf(y)dy$

So after you work out the PDF with the differentiation if you want to be completely sure about your work you could integrate and verify the second condition. Since the CDF characterize the probability then you can be sure that $f(x)$ is a PDF for $P$. Hope this helps!